# Page size adjusting with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm struggling to print labels that are 28mm x 89mm.  I've set up TCPDF like this:

```
require_once JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

    $width = 28;
    $height = 89;

    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', 'pt', ['format' => [$width, $height], 'Rotate' => 90]);

    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10, '', false);
    $pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0, true);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $htmlToUse = 'John Smith';

    $htmlToUse2 = '7 Space Way';

    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $htmlToUse, 0, 0, 0, true, '', true);
    $pdf->writeHTMLCell(100, 100, '2', '55', $htmlToUse2, 0, 0, 0, true, '', true);

    $docnname = "labelCardTestv2.pdf";

    $pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $docnname, 'F');
```

But it just gives a square type page tha t is obviously too big.

I'm using @version 4.9.005